# join() vs JSON.stringify() with Array full of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an array packed with objects:

```
array = [{...}, {...}, {...}];
```

I want to turn this array into a string to be able to add it to localStorage.
For this I use:

```
array.join()
```

My output is:

```
// [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

Now I use

```
JSON.stringify(array);
```

...and it works as intended.
My output is:

```
// [{text}, {text}, {text}]
```

Why doesn't 'join()' work like 'stringify()' here?

Comment: Can you specify what kind of objects the 'array' consists of ? An example of the 'array' variable.

Comment: JSON.stringify is for serialization, Array.prototype.join is not

Comment: Because `({}).toString()` returns `"[object Object]"` ... It's a weird question...

Comment: If you want to store it as a string for later recovery, then JSON is actually a possible solution. `Array.join` is weird here, as already said it's just using the existing `toString()` in your objects, and second how would you read the object back from local storage? JSON has `JSON.parse` for that. Note for your further research : processes of saving relevant data as a simple representation (like a string) and getting it back are called "serialization" and "deserialization".

Answer (score 0):

> Why doesn't 'join()' work like 'stringify()' here?

Because `join` and `stringify` have 2 completely different meanings. From the man pages;

- [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) creates and returns a new string by concatenating all of the elements in an array, separated by commas or a specified separator string.
- [`stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) converts a JavaScript object or value to a JSON string.

The `join()` works as expected, but will not convert the object to a string, which is exactly what `stringify()` does.

So there is no need for the `join()` command;

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify([ { a: 1 }, { b: 2 } ] ));
// String: [{"a":1},{"b":2}]
```

Answer (score -1):

The goal of the `join` function is to "join" array elements into a single string (with separator or not), so `join` function takes the string representation of each object and do a concatenation of them.

In your case, the string representation of `{...}` is `[object Object]`, but you can define it to whatever you want with the `toString()` method. For example with the code below:

```js
class MyClass {
    firstname = 'John';
    lastname = 'Doe';

    toString() {
        return this.firstname + " " + this.lastname;
    }
}

const a = [new MyClass, new MyClass];
console.log(a.join()); // --> "John Doe,John Doe"
```

The JSON representation is just a serialization of your object: it encodes all the attributes and their values, and is very usefull to be recovered into an object later.